# Command prompt notation for java

Tags: java

I am familiar with two dots (..) to refer to parent directory, but what does one dot (.) mean?

example:

```
".\\text.txt"
```

Thanks!

Comment: It means the current working directory.

Answer (score 5):

One dot refers to the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

One dot simply means your current working directory